# Localizing of a chart panel's popup menu and its menu items

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart library 1.0.19 in my Java Swing project. I want to localize my JFreeChart's popup/context menu and it's menu items—like "properties", "save as", "zoom in", etc.—in real time from English to French and vice versa. As it is built into the library, it is fetching the native language of the operating system. Is there any way to localize it?

Comment: Earlier [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41660623/230513) closed. Have you tried changing your platform's language/keyboard settings?

Comment: platform means OS's language ? .. if it means that then yes when i changed my OS's language then jfree chart all it's component is fetching it's native language.

Comment: however i don't want to be OS's language dependent as i am making GUI in which i have added two button English and French respectively and by selecting that one of the buttons jfree chart should change according to that language ..

Comment: is there any way to make it OS"s language independent ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make [the menu] language independent?

The [`createPopupMenu()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#createPopupMenu-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-) method, seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#line.3054), uses an instance of [`ResourceBundleWrapper`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/ResourceBundleWrapper.html) to obtain localized properties for the context menu. You'll need to override the method in `ChartPanel` to use properties obtained from a bundle for a `Locale` that's passed as a parameter to your subclass.

Comment: yes , i am doing this but , as my operating system's language is french so it is fetching all the words in french, even the ResourceBundleWrapper has the English Bundle by default in the library.

Comment: Even when you give `getBundle()` a specific `Locale`? A [mcve] may shed light.

Comment: ChartPanel = new ChartPanel(timeChart);
ChartPanel.setVisible(true);

Comment: and as this "ChartPanel" is from the default jar file , so how it can be access then ?